# Can a Tressym see a Skulk?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, magic, invisibility

Is a skulk's invisibility is magical enough to be detected by a tressym's Detect Invisibility? Or is it just a nonmagical ability?

Comment: Maybe show the rules on both and how you think they interact, and we can say yes or no. The downvote isn't mine, but it it probably because the question doesn't show much research. Given the description of both powers, what do you think? And why are you not sure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The skulk's ability is not magical

The lore entry about the [skulk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/motm/bestiary-su#Skulk) reads as follows (MP:MotM, p. 219):

> They are so devoid of identity that they have become permanently invisible. Only children can see a skulk without the help of a mirror or a special candle.

So their invisibility is not due to a magical effect; it is due to lacking identity.

There are also [guidelines in the Sage Advice Compendium](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA224) on how to determine something is magical:

> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?

The [skulk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/2560916-skulk)'s invisibility is not a magic item, spell attack, not fueled by spell slots. It says (MP:MotM, p. 219):

> ***Fallible Invisibility.*** The skulk is invisible. This invisibility can be circumvented by three things:
>
> - **Charnel Candles**. The skulk appears as a dim, translucent form in the light of a candle made of fat rendered from a corpse whose identity is unknown.
> - **Children**. Humanoid children, aged 10 and under, can see through this invisibility.
> - **Reflective Surfaces**. The skulk appears as a drab, smooth-skinned biped if its reflection can be seen in a mirror or on another surface.

Nowhere does it say it is magical, or reference a spell, so it is not magical.

The [Tressym](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17353-tressym)'s Detect Invisibility trait says (here from *Storm King‘s Thunder*, page 243; emphasis mine):

> ***Detect Invisibility.*** Within 60 feet of the tressym, **magical** invisi­bility fails to conceal anything from the tressym's sight.

Since the skulk's invisibility is not magical, it will work against the tressym.

Comment: sweet that's what i was thinking thanks!